# How to refresh the token in AWS Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

My app making use of AWS Cognito. So using the **setLogins()** method, i am setting the identity token to communicate AWS Cognito. After this, I can able to make successful call to AWS using the mCognitoSyncManager which was initialized with the identity token.

So, my question is:

1) How can i refresh the token with newly generated token?

1.1)  one thing i know is, that i have initialize the CredentialsProvider with the new token. but i don't want to do that.

2.1) Whether the AWS will ask me to return the new token. if so how it will ask me.

Could you pls anyone help me on this. I struggled with it for last two days.

The code is below:

```
 void initCognito() {

     mCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(mContext, IDENTITY_POOL_ID, Regions.US_EAST_2);

     Map<String, String> logins = credentialsProvider.getLogins();

     if (logins == null) {
        logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
     }

     logins.put(DOMAIN, "token");

     credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

     mCognitoSyncManager = new CognitoSyncManager(mContext, Regions.US_EAST_2, credentialsProvider);

 }
```

Comment: Anyone there to help. at-least some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about what you are asking, so let me start by summarizing your question, based on my understanding.

You have previously got a JWT from your signin system and were able to successfully use that to get AWS Credentials using Cognito. Now, you have a new ( or refreshed token) from your signin system and want to use that with Cognito.

If that is correct, then what you will have to do is to call the `credentialsProvider.refresh` after you set the new token using `credentialsProvider.setLogins`.

Please look at the API documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.html#setLogins-java.util.Map- for more information.